# Avoid MemoryError and improve performance when merging big files in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I'm using `Python 3.7` with `Pandas 0.24.2`. I need to merge 5 different CSV files into one big file (or potentialy more) using Pandas Dataframe Merge/Join. The size of each dataframe are:

```
Dataframe A : 120,523 rows × 60 columns
Dataframe B : 1,886,229 rows × 27 columns
Dataframe C : 17,512 rows × 12 columns
Dataframe D : 207,982 rows × 54 columns
Dataframe E : 35,547 rows × 44 columns
```

The Dataframes contain information of people, so I use the ID of each person for join the Dataframes. Unfortunately, the files are big enough to eat my 16GB of RAM, so my code stops with `MemoryError`.
I have read several optimizations for using big files in Pandas and I already use the following steps to improve performance:

1. Skipped as many columns as possible (I can't delete any more columns or I would loose critical information)
2. Declare the more optimal data dtypes with the dtype option: Currently I'm using object for each column except ages (`int64`) and dates (`datetime64[ns]`)
3. Declare `chunksize=10000` and `compression='gzip'` when I try to create the final CSV file. I do this with final_dataframe.to_csv(...)
4. Set ID as the index of each of the 5 Dataframes, as some guys have notably better performance with this step

If you have any other ideas to improve performance and avoid MemoryError, I would ve thankful.
Thank you for your time!

Pd.: Sorry for my English, I'm a native Spanish speaker

Comment: Could you try getting a list of IDs and combining only a few at a time? Maybe select 100 people, merge and write to the destination. Good English, by the way.

Comment: When I read `MemoryError` I automatically think [Dask](https://dask.org/), specifically [Dask.DataFrame](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html). It keeps big files on disk but lets you perform pandas operations on bigger-than-memory data. Merge everything into a single dask.dataframe (basically a computational graph of operations to be done), and write it out to csv again. You'll have to do some reading and practicing, but I found it to be a big help in these situations.